# Publish website using Visual Studio 2013 for Visual Studio 2005 projects

Tags: .net, visual-studio, webforms, web, publish

For the project I am working on, I'm using **.NET framework 2.0** and **Visual Studio 2005** as my IDE.

The question is, now I am going to upgrade my IDE from **VS2005** to **VS2013**, but I wish to keep the .NET framework as it is for now (will upgrade later),

if I publish a website using **VS2013** and my client server only has **VS2005** installed, will it work? Is the publish depend on the .NET framework version or the IDE?

p/s: Sorry for my bad english.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual studio 2013 can publish in multiple frameworks, so that ability will not change. You can publish from .NET Framework 2 to the latest beta, it doesn't care. For more detailed info on what all, exactly, is supported in 2013 you can check out the MSDN documentation in the subject: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747.aspx

What will change though is once 2013 opens the project and upgrades it your visual studio 2005 IDE will not be able to open the project. Round tripping from and to older versions of visual studio is only supported from 2010 up.

I should mention, I don't believe 2013 will support any framework older than 2, not that you should be using .NET Framework 1 or 1.1 anywhere but it is worth mentioning just in case.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. You cured my headache :D

Comment: One more question, if I am using TortoiseSVN to commit and receive updates from other developer that uses VS2005, will it be a problem?

Comment: Should ask that as a new question @HoChiaLeung. The short answer is yes, the .csproj and solution files are not compatible between the two versions. There are ways around it and workarounds but ask as a new question to get more detailed answers..

Comment: sorry about that and thanks for the answer :). I think the best way is to get everyone up to the same IDE :D